# how to clear form data without refresh page

Tags: javascript

After I submit the form, I want to add a new entry which is working, but i don't want the data to remain in the form i.e. reset the form

here is the form code

```
 <form id="add_multycontact" action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns">
         <label>Company Name</label>
          <input name="company" type="text">
      </div>

     <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label>Contact Name </label>
         <input name="contact_name" type="text">
    </div>
  </div><!--end row-->

  <div class="row">
   <div class="large-6 columns">
       <label>Main Phone</label>
       <input name="mainPhone" type="text">
    </div>

     <div class="large-6 columns">
       <label>Alt Phone</label>
       <input name="altPhone" type="text">
    </div>
  </div><!--end row-->

  <div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Street Address </label>
        <input name="street_address" type="text">
  </div>

   <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>City </label>
        <input name="city" type="text">
   </div>  
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Province</label>
         <select name="province">
            <option>Select Province</option>
            <?php foreach($provinces as $key => $value) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>

   <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Postal Code </label>
        <input name="postal" type="text">
   </div> 

  </div><!--end row-->


    <div class="row">     
  <div class="large-4 columns">
       <label>Group
        <select name="contact_group">
            <option>Select Contact Group</option>
          <option value="client">Client</option>
          <option value="supplier">Supplier</option>
          <option value="employee">Employee</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      </div>         
     </div>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" class="add_btn button right small" value="submit"> 
     <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>

</form>

        </div>
     </div> 
    </div>

 <!--Loading Image-->
<div id="loaderImage">
    <img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif">
 </div>

 <!--Main Content-->
    <div id="pageContent"></div>



 <script src="../js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/foundation.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/vendor/fastclick.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/multyCONTACTscript.js"></script>   



    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //show loader image
$('#loaderImage').show();

    //show contacts on page load
    showContacts();


    //add contact
    $(document).on('submit','#add_multycontact', function(){
        //show loader image
    $('#loaderImage').show();



    //post data from form
    $.post('../multy/add_multyCONTACT.php',$(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
                $('#addModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
                    showContacts();
        });
        return false;
    });

    //edit contact
    $(document).on('submit','#edit_multycontact', function(){
        //show loader image
    $('#loaderImage').show();

    //post data from form
    $.post("../multy/edit_multyCONTACT.php",$(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
                $('.editModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
                    showContacts();
        });
        return false;
    });

    //delete contact
    $(document).on('submit','#delete_multycontact', function(){
        //show loader image
    $('#loaderImage').show();

    //post data from form
    $.post("../multy/delete_multyCONTACT.php",$(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
                showContacts();
        });
        return false;
    });

});
    //show contacts
    function showContacts() {
    console.log('Showing Contacts...');
    setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('../multy/multycontacts.php',function(){$('#loaderImage').hide();})", 1000);
}

//close the modal
$(document).on('click', '.close-reveal-modal', function() {

//this is the latest attempt that is just plain desperate!!
document.getElementById("add_multycontact").reset() 

$('.reveal-modal').foundation('reveal', 'close');

});
```

I want to make consecutive multiple entries but after adding one entry and then clicking to add another, the pop up opens with the data from the prvious entry, unless i refresh the web page...and i dont wanna do that!

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question to not include any swears/curses or unnecessary descriptions of your feelings. And screaming doesn't make anything better (at least not in this context).

Comment: tried `$("#form-id").trigger('reset')`?

Comment: I assume this question has nothing to do with PHP, right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are calling the `reset` method `document.getElementById("add_multycontact").reset()` at the wrong place. This will only be called once on `$(document).ready`. So, you need to call that before or just after opening the modal with form.

Even if that does not work, then try this in place of `reset`:

```
$('#add_multycontact select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
$('#add_multycontact input[type="text"]').val('');
```

Comment: this seems to have worked nicely Bhaskar, thank you so very much! All I needed to do was add the 2nd (type=text.val) line to the correct code block and it worked just perfect! :)  - i tried to click that UP arrow on the left to make it say1..but i dont have enough credits?!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `<button type="button> </button>` in your html it shouldn't refresh the page and you may use js click events on your button to continue the application running next steps. If you want require elements of the form to continue you may use js to make the button have a not-allowed cursor style if the form isn't filled.